# data-ng-class conditions is not working when changing url manually

Tags: angularjs, url, controller, ng-class, route-provider

I did a conditional statement on the div on data-ng-class and I want to somehow add this scope to the controller and specify when the url is /vegetarian to apply class 'egg' and i manually change url i want the class 'bacon' to be applied, but its not working, where I have i gone wrong?

html:

```
<div data-ng-class="{'egg': isVeggie, 'bacon': !isVeggie }">
  Text here
</div>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('foodCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {

  $scope.location = $location;
  $scope.isVeggie = false;


  $scope.isVeggie = function() {
    if(isVeggie === $location.path('/vegetarian')) {
      return true;
    }
  }

});
```

this is not working.  When I type /vegetarian, the class egg is being applied, but when I change the url to something else like /breakfast, the class 'egg' remains.  How can I make this work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the property and the function with the same name ? After all you will have only the function

```
$scope.isVeggie = false;

$scope.isVeggie = function() {
    if(isVeggie === $location.path('/vegetarian')) {
       return true;
    }
}
```

Change your code to have only the function.

**Only**

```
$scope.isVeggie = function() {
        if(isVeggie === $location.path('/vegetarian')) {
           return true;
        }
    }
```

and markup

```
<div data-ng-class="{'egg': isVeggie(), 'bacon': !isVeggie() }">
  Text here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You bind you ng-class directive to the property isVeggie and not the function isVeggie().

Change your html to:

```
<div data-ng-class="{'egg': isVeggie(), 'bacon': !isVeggie() }">
  Text here
</div>
```

You can then remove the following line in your controller:

```
$scope.isVeggie = false;
```